# why not we pass asterisk(*) in iterator in stl

Tags: c++, stl

When we use iterator we declare iterator and then `itr` as an object, but we don't pass any pointer like we do every time when declaring pointer variable but when we print the value of vector by the use of iterator than how `itr` became`*itr`
when we doesn't pass any pointer

Is pointer is hidden or its work on the background?

Example like:

```
iterator itr;
*itr
```

How it works does `*` means any other things to iterator or `*itr` act like normal pointer variable.

If it works like a pointer variable then why we do not pass `*` when declaring `itr`.

Comment: Please use punctuation marks.

Comment: Please open your book on the chapter about *operator overloading*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How it works does * means any other things to iterator or *itr act like normal pointer variable.

It depends what type stands behind `iterator`. It can be alias for a pointer:

```
using iterator = int *;
iterator itr;
*itr; // it is pointer dereferencing in this case.
```

Or it can be a user defined type:

```
struct iterator {
    int &operator*();
};

iterator itr;
*itr; // it means itr.operator*() here
```

So without knowing what type `iterator` is it is quite impossible to say what `*` actually does here. But in reality you should not care as developers of the library should implement it the way it would not matter for you.

Answer (score 2):

An iterator is an object that lets you travel (or iterate) over each object in a collection or stream. It is a sort of generalization of pointers. That is, pointers are one example of an iterator.

Iterators implement concepts required by various algorithms such as forward iteration (meaning it can be incremented to move forward in the collection), bi-directional iteration (meaning it can go forward and backward), and random access (meaning you can use an index an arbitrary item in the collection).

For instance, moving backward can't typically happen in a stream, so stream's iterators are typically forward iterators only because once you access a value, you can't go back in the stream. A linked list's iterators are bi-directional because you can move forward or backward, but you cannot access them by indexing because the nodes are not typically in contiguous memory, so you can't calculate with an index where an arbitrary element is. A vector's iterators are random access and very much like pointers. (C++20 made [these categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) more precise, so the old categories are now called "Legacy".)

Iterators can also have special functions, such as `std::back_inserter`, which appends items to the end of a container when a value is assigned to it's referrent.

So, you can see that iterators allow you to be more precise in defining what your consumer of iterators expects. If your algorithm requires bi-directional iteration, you can communicate that and limit it so it won't work with forward-only iterators.

As for the `*` operator, it is similar to the `*` operator for a pointer. In both cases, it means, "give me the value referred to by this handle". It is implemented via operator overloading. You do not need the `*` when declaring an iterator because it is not a pointer, which is a lower-level construct in the language. Rather, it is an object with pointer-like semantics.

---

To answer your questions below:

No, the `*` is not automatically created. When you declare an iterator you are declaring an object. When the class for that object is defined, it may or may not have an operator overload for the `*` operator (or the `==` or the `+` or any other operators).

When you go to use the object, such as passing it to a function, the types will need to match up. If a function you were passing it to requires an iterator (e.g. `std::sort()`), then no dereferencing `*` is needed. If the function was expecting a value of the type the iterator refers to, then you would need to dereference it first. In that case the compiler calls the overloaded operator `*`and returns the value.

That is the nature of overloaded operators -- they look like ordinary operators but ultimately are resolved to a function call defined by the creator of the class. It works the same as if you defined a matrix class that has plus and minus operators overloaded.

Comment: does it mean that * automatically created

Comment: or known by compiler

Comment: I added an attempt to answer your question above.